# Observable.just Access multiple params

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

In the following code when I print `s` I get the first `String` that is given as the parameter of `Observable.just` .

```
Observable.just("Str1","Str2","str3")
    .map(new Func1<String, Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object call(String s) {
            System.out.println(s)
            return "test";
        }
    });
```

How do I get the rest of the parameters inside `call` Method ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observable.just()` will emit the passed arguments one-by-one. You can wrap them in an array or a `List` to treat them as a single object:

```java
String[] array = new String[] {"Str1", "Str2", "str3"};
Observable.just(array)
          .map(new Func1<String[], Object>() {
              @Override
              public Object call(String[] strings) {
                  return null;
              }
          });
```